# XSLT html mixed table body

Tags: xml, html, xslt

I have a sample XML which needs to be rendered to html. When the OBX.5 is greater than 20 characters, I want to show it in a paragraph other wise the atomic values of the same need to be clubbed into a table. I tried the XSL below, but it produces empty table and nothing in the paragraph. What should be  corrected in the XSL  for the desired output?
I also want to assign the table header. So how do I detect the OBX.5 is a free-text(>30) or atomic type and setup the table in the XSLT?

XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ORU.ORC_OBR__OBX_NTE>
    <OBX>
        <OBX.5>Negative by specific anti-\.br\human haemoglobin antibody method.\.br\This suggests proximal G.I.T. bleed or diet/drug interference.\</OBX.5>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <OBX.5>No Salmonella, Shigella, Campylobacter or Yersinia isolated</OBX.5>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
            <OBX.5>THROAT</OBX.5>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
            <OBX.5>NEGATIVE</OBX.5>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
            <OBX.5>129</OBX.5>
    </OBX>

</ORU.ORC_OBR__OBX_NTE>
```

XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">       
      <th>OBX.5</th>
    </tr>

                        <xsl:for-each select="ORU.ORC_OBR__OBX_NTE/OBX">                          
                                <xsl:variable name="result">                                                                                        
                                    <b><xsl:value-of select="OBX.5"/></b>
                                </xsl:variable>                              

                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="string-length($result) &lt; 30">
                                               <tr><td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
                                            </td> </tr>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <p class="notes">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
                                                <br/>
                                            </p>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>

                            </xsl:for-each>


                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

HTML I get is

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>OBX.5</th>
            </tr>
            <p class="notes">Negative by specific anti-\.br\human haemoglobin antibody method.\.br\This suggests proximal G.I.T. bleed or diet/drug interference.\<br></p>
            <p class="notes">No Salmonella, Shigella, Campylobacter or Yersinia isolated<br></p>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">THROAT</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">NEGATIVE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">129</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

HTML I want as result is

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p class="notes">Negative by specific anti-\.br\human haemoglobin antibody method.\.br\This suggests proximal G.I.T. bleed or diet/drug interference.\<br></p>
            <p class="notes">No Salmonella, Shigella, Campylobacter or Yersinia isolated<br></p>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>OBX.5</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">THROAT</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">NEGATIVE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">129</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Additional examples:
Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ORU.ORC_OBR__OBX_NTE>
    <OBX>
        <OBX.5>Negative by specific anti-\.br\human haemoglobin antibody method.\.br\This suggests proximal G.I.T. bleed or diet/drug interference.\</OBX.5>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <OBX.5>No Salmonella, Shigella, Campylobacter or Yersinia isolated</OBX.5>
    </OBX>
    <NTE>
        <NTE.3>After the 5 dots is a Carat.....^\.br\</NTE.3>
    </NTE>
    <OBX>
        <OBX.5>THROAT</OBX.5>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <OBX.5>NEGATIVE</OBX.5>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <OBX.5>Yersinia isolated</OBX.5>
    </OBX>
    <NTE>
        <NTE.3>After the 5 dots is a Carat.....^\.br\</NTE.3>
    </NTE>
    <OBX>
        <OBX.5>129</OBX.5>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <OBX.5>129</OBX.5>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <OBX.5>130</OBX.5>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <OBX.5>131</OBX.5>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <OBX.5>132</OBX.5>
    </OBX>
    <NTE>
        <NTE.3>After the 5 dots is a Carat.....^\.br\</NTE.3>
    </NTE>
</ORU.ORC_OBR__OBX_NTE>
```

Output html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p class="notes">
        Negative by specific anti-\.br\human haemoglobin antibody method.\.br\This suggests proximal G.I.T. bleed or diet/drug interference.\
    <br></p>
        <p class="notes">
        No Salmonella, Shigella, Campylobacter or Yersinia isolated
    <br></p>
    <p class="footnote">
        After the 5 dots is a Carat.....^\.br\
    <br></p>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>OBX.5</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
        THROAT
    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
        NEGATIVE
    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
        Yersinia isolated
    </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p class="footnote">
        After the 5 dots is a Carat.....^\.br\
    <br></p>

        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>OBX.5</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
        129
    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
        129
    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
        130
    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
        131
    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
        132
    </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <p class="footnote">
        After the 5 dots is a Carat.....^\.br\
    <br></p>





    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post the expected result of your example, please? I am not sure what exactly "clubbed into a table" means.

Comment: I am afraid I don't quite follow the logic of the transformation: do you want to group the values by their length? First all the "long" values as `<p>`s, then all the "short" values in a single table - regardless of their order in the source document?

Comment: That is correct. If there is a atomic value of OBX.5 such as THROAT it needs to go to a table, but if it is more that a word such as LEFT SHOULDER, it needs to go to a para

Comment: Also, the atomic values always need to go to the table regardless of their order

Comment: Okay, so doesn't my suggestion do that?

Comment: yep. that worked fine. i added another sample. any help would be appreciated

Comment: I am sorry, I don't follow. Isn't this question answered? If not, why not?

Comment: yes, the earlier question was answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ORU.ORC_OBR__OBX_NTE/OBX[string-length(.) >= 30]" mode="p"/>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">       
                    <th>OBX.5</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ORU.ORC_OBR__OBX_NTE/OBX[string-length(.) &lt; 30]" mode="tr"/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>             

<xsl:template match="OBX" mode="p">             
    <p class="notes">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <br/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>                                              

<xsl:template match="OBX" mode="tr">            
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>                                              


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return the required result in your example case. As I said in the comments, I am not sure what you want to do when the short and long values are interspersed.

Note also that the table is created without checking if any short values exist - you might want to add that yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the XML and also updated the expected output